# Trigger with multiple inserts based on JSON data

Tags: trigger, insert, sqlite, json

I am using sqlite and have its json1 extension available. I have the following tables (reduced to a minimal example):

```
-- table filled from external source,
-- with only a little possible impact on data
create table "source" (
    "id" Integer primary key,
    "json_data" Text not NULL
);

-- table to be filled using a trigger on "source"
create table "target" (
    "node" Text primary key,
    "parent" Text, -- NULL when root of a tree
    "kind" Text  -- NULL when "parent" is NULL
        check ("kind" in ('clone', 'child', 'offspring'))
) without rowid;
```

The `"json_data"` is of the following form:

```js
{
    'id': [n0]  // single-component list
    'clone_ids': ['c2', 'c1'],  // multi-component list
    'parent_id': ['p0'],  // single-component list
    'ancestor_ids': ['a1, a2, p0']
        // single-component list, but multiple semantic components
}
```

This instance of `"json_data"` should give rise to the following tuples being inserted into `"target" ( "node", "parent", "kind")`:

```
'c2', 'c1', 'clone'
'c1', 'n0', 'clone'
'n0', 'p0', 'child'
'p0', 'a2', 'offspring'
'a2', 'a1', 'offspring'
'a1', NULL, NULL
```

Usually, `'clone_ids'` will be absent; often `'parent_id'` and `'ancestor_ids'` will be absent; even `'id'` could be absent. So the approach should be robust in view of this.

The `'child'` kind is an ‘upgrade’ from the `'offspring'` one; my feeling was that this upgrade could be done as an update at the end.

So my idea was that I should first try and get a list (as a JSON string or perhaps a temporary table) of the form

```js
[
    ["c2", "clone"],
    ["c1", "clone"],
    ["n0", "offspring"],
    ["p0", "offspring"],
    ["a2", "offspring"],
    ["a1", null]
]
```

and then create the variable number of inserts from this list.

However, I'm quite inexperienced with SQL and sqlite's json1 extension, so I do not know (i) whether this is possible, and if yes (ii) how. So I would like to get responses to both questions. In case getting the latter list of pairs needs to be done using an external function (which I would do in Python), I still appreciate guidance on how to go from the list to the inserts.

---

*EDIT:*

In a comment it has been indicated that what I asked is not possible. So I would like to amend my question in the following way: Assume I have a user-defined function that produces the following JSON:

```js
[
    ["c2", "c1", "clone"],
    ["c1", "n0", "clone"],
    ["n0", "p0", "offspring"],
    ["p0", "a2", "offspring"],
    ["a2", "a1", "offspring"],
    ["a1", null, null]
]
```

So, essentially the tuples I want to insert.

How would I go about inserting them?

Comment: As far as I can see, doing this in SQL would require a recursive CTE, which is not allowed in a trigger.

Comment: @CL.: Thanks for the hint. I have amended my question accordingly (I think).

Comment: I'm not really sure whether the original object could be transformed in a similar way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid JSON; strings require double quotes.

Anyway, the table-valued function [json_each()](http://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach) allows to enumerate a dynamically-sized array:

```
SELECT * FROM json_each('[["c2","c1","clone"],["c1","n0","clone"],["n0","p0","offspring"],["p0","a2","offspring"],["a2","a1","offspring"],["a1",null,null]]');
key         value                type        atom        id          parent      fullkey     path
----------  -------------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           ["c2","c1","clone"]  array                   1                       $[0]        $
1           ["c1","n0","clone"]  array                   5                       $[1]        $
2           ["n0","p0","offspri  array                   9                       $[2]        $
3           ["p0","a2","offspri  array                   13                      $[3]        $
4           ["a2","a1","offspri  array                   17                      $[4]        $
5           ["a1",null,null]     array                   21                      $[5]        $
```

For extracting the values from an array with a known size, we can use [json_extract()](http://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jex):

```
SELECT json_extract(value, '$[0]'), json_extract(value, '$[1]'), json_extract(value, '$[2]')
FROM json_each('[["c2","c1","clone"],["c1","n0","clone"],["n0","p0","offspring"],["p0","a2","offspring"],["a2","a1","offspring"],["a1",null,null]]');
c2          c1          clone
c1          n0          clone
n0          p0          offspring
p0          a2          offspring
a2          a1          offspring
a1
```

This can then simply be plugged into an INSERT … SELECT … statement.

Comment: I fixed the invalid JSON you pointed out.